# Web API - ProtoBufFormatter - return serializable 401 with custom Authorize attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, authorize-attribute

Our problem is following: we are using the **ProtoBufFormatter** in our Web API.

```
config.Formatters.Add(new ProtoBufFormatter());
```

Also using our custom **Authorize** attribute. The problem is when our Web API is returning 401. Which results in Protobuf throwing and exception as it can't serialize the response, so it throws following exception:

> No serializer defined for type: System.Object

When I comment out:

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            // base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
        }
```

the server stops throwing the exception as this prevents it to send the 401 response.

But I am not sure how to deal the best with this issue.

Should I then in my controller actions return a protobuf serializable response that contains that user is unauthorized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by returning our serializable content in the response as following:

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
                new ApiResponse(false, ApiErrorMessages.Unauthorized, ErrorType.Unauthorized));
        }
```